# HTML Within Loop Not Rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I'm attempting to list queried posts in the DOM using Gatsby. The small snippet below should suffice because the Graphql query is correctly fetching data. This snippet is within the component, which is also rendering correctly. I'm new to Gatsby and React, and I hope I'm missing something pretty basic.

```
<div className="container">
  Hello! // Renders
  {newsItems.map(newsItem => {
    console.log(newsItem.context.id); // Logs each news item id to console correctly
    Hello! // Does not render
    <p>{newsItem.context.id}</p> // Does not render
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: Your map function doesn't _return_ anything, so your component renders `undefined` for each newsItem.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Strangely the example I copied this from did not return anything either. I figured it was just some syntactic "magic." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BueGgzV4kw

Comment: Arrow functions can have an [implicit return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body), but if you use a block (if you include curly braces) the return has to be explicit. I didn't look at the example you're following, but I suspect it is either using parentheses or a naked value, not curly braces.

Comment: Right again! Thanks for your help. I always feel bad about these kinds of questions because they don't generally help people. I wrote an arrow function the way I'm accustomed to doing and it never even registered that the example used parentheses.

Comment: It's a subtle distinction, easily overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used curly braces, so this is how you return component from map function.

```
{newsItems.map(newsItem => {
    console.log(newsItem.context.id); // Logs each news item id to console correctly
    return (
        <>
            Hello!
            <p>{newsItem.context.id}</p>
        </>
   )
})}
```

Haven't tried this, but it should work. This also only works if `newsItems` contains values. [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) `<>...</>` were used because return must only return single component. You could also use `<div>...</div>` instead of fragment.

Try this.

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes. Answer accepted.